# prove that $f(x)=\ln x$ is a differentiable function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

> prove that $f(x)=\ln x:=\int_1^x dt/t$ is a differentiable function:

**My Try**:

$$\lim_{x\to a} \dfrac{\ln x-\ln a}{x-a}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to a} \dfrac{\ln(\dfrac{x}{a})}{x-a}=?$$

now what ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous on an interval containing $a$, then
$$g(x)=\int_a^xf(t)\,dt$$
is a differentiable function, with derivative $g'(x)=f(x)$.
This is the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, as José Carlos Santos has said.

Answer (score 4):

It follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and from your definition of $\ln$ that $\ln'(x)=\frac1x$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

First fundamental theorem of integral calculus.

B.t.w.,  you have a mistake: $\;\ln x=\displaystyle\int_{\color{red}1}^x\frac{\mathrm dt}t $ for all $x>0$.